# Find the maximum value of given expression $S = \Sigma f_r.\log(P_r)$

Tags: maximum-likelihood

With $\Sigma f_r=1$ and $\Sigma P_r=1$, $\forall f_r, P_r>0$. How to find the maximum value of $S$ where:

$$
S = \Sigma f_r.\log(P_r)
$$

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I am answering because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

You have $S \leq 0$.

Which means that the maximum of $S$ is $0$. (in the case $f_r = P_r = \delta_{ri}$, when the probability mass functions correspond to [Kronecker deltas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)).

---

From your question, I'm wondering if your $S$ shouldn't be the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of a probability function. In that case I'll revise my answer.